# Insert into table with autoincrement primary key

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating a table as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    "password TEXT NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('testuser', 'textpassword')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

But when I try to insert a user, I'm getting the following exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table users has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO users VALUES ('testuser', 'textpassword')

As `_id` is the primarykey, why is it expecting it? I also tried `AUTOINCREMENT` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String sql =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                "name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "password TEXT NOT NULL);";
db.execSQL(sql);

sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, password) VALUES ('testuser', 'textpassword')";
db.execSQL(sql);
}

AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL is missing in your insert query which will increase the value of _id field automatically.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the values you're inserting:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, password) VALUES ('testuser', 'textpassword')";
```

There's no need to specify AUTOINCREMENT: [On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: that is for 'ROWID' column whichis auto generated by SQL. But in this case he is creating his own column in 'Create Table command.'

Comment: It's for "ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY". Autoincrement assures db level uniqueness, paying some performance costs, which generally you don't need.

Comment: yup right, so ivan don't need to create '_id' column in his create table command at all.